# How to create a group or category column based on certain conditions in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of vehicle names and I want to group them into certain categories in a new column. I have created a list of these categories and using if statements to populate the new column. somehow it's not working and giving me only 'NA' for all the values. see the groups and example below.

```
Two_W_Personal = ['MOPED', 'M-CYCLE/SCOOTER', 'M-CYCLE/SCOOTER-WITH SIDE CAR', 'MOTORISED CYCLE (CC > 25CC)']
Two_W_Shared = ['MOTOR CYCLE/SCOOTER-USED FOR HIRE']
Three_W_Personal = ['THREE WHEELER (PERSONAL)']
Three_W_Shared = ['THREE WHEELER (PASSENGER)']
Three_W_Shared_LowSpeed = ['E-RICKSHAW(P)']
Three_W_Goods = ['THREE WHEELER (GOODS)']
Three_W_Goods_LowSpeed = ['E-RICKSHAW WITH CART (G)']
Four_W_Personal = ['MOTOR CAR']
Four_W_Shared = ['MOTOR CAB', 'LUXURY CAB', 'LUXURY CAB']
Bus = ['BUS', 'OMNI BUS', 'OMNI BUS (PRIVATE USE)']
Institution_Bus = ['EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTION BUS']
```

The above are the categories that I want.

The below is the code that I'm running to populate the new column 'vehicle type'. For e.g., if the 'vehicle class' column (it is an existing column in the database) has the value 'MOTOR CAR', my new column 'vehicle type' must have the value '4W_Personal'

```
for vehicle in master_df['Vehicle Class']:
    if vehicle in Two_W_Personal:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '2W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Two_W_Shared:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '2W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Personal:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Shared:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Shared_LowSpeed:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Shared_LowSpeed'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Goods:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Goods'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Goods_LowSpeed:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Goods_LowSpeed'
    elif vehicle in Four_W_Personal:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '4W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Four_W_Shared:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = '4W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Bus:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = 'Bus'
    elif vehicle in Institution_Bus:
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = 'Institution Bus'
    else: 
        master_df['Vehicle Type'] = 'NA'
```

Somehow my new column has only the value 'NA' getting populated in it.

What am I doing wrong and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are giving the 'Vehicle Type' column a single value all at once instead of giving each row its own value.

If you wanted to fix your code you can try something like this:

```
for idx, vehicle in master_df['Vehicle Class'].items():
    if vehicle in Two_W_Personal:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '2W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Two_W_Shared:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '2W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Personal:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Shared:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Shared_LowSpeed:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Shared_LowSpeed'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Goods:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Goods'
    elif vehicle in Three_W_Goods_LowSpeed:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '3W_Goods_LowSpeed'
    elif vehicle in Four_W_Personal:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '4W_Personal'
    elif vehicle in Four_W_Shared:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = '4W_Shared'
    elif vehicle in Bus:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = 'Bus'
    elif vehicle in Institution_Bus:
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = 'Institution Bus'
    else: 
        master_df.loc[idx, 'Vehicle Type'] = 'NA'
```

Anyway, it's not the best approach to this kind of problem. It will be better if you create a dict of Vehicle Types and then you use `.map()` to assign the values to the corresponding row. This is how to do it..

```
vehicle_type_dict = {
    '2W_Personal': ['MOPED', 'M-CYCLE/SCOOTER', 'M-CYCLE/SCOOTER-WITH SIDE CAR', 'MOTORISED CYCLE (CC > 25CC)'],
    '2W_Shared': ['MOTOR CYCLE/SCOOTER-USED FOR HIRE'],
    '3W_Personal': ['THREE WHEELER (PERSONAL)'],
    '3W_Shared': ['THREE WHEELER (PASSENGER)'],
    '3W_Shared_LowSpeed': ['E-RICKSHAW(P)'],
    '3W_Goods': ['THREE WHEELER (GOODS)'],
    '3W_Goods_LowSpeed': ['E-RICKSHAW WITH CART (G)'],
    '4W_Personal': ['MOTOR CAR'],
    '4W_Shared': ['MOTOR CAB', 'LUXURY CAB', 'LUXURY CAB'],
    'Bus': ['BUS', 'OMNI BUS', 'OMNI BUS (PRIVATE USE)'],
    'Institution Bus': ['EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTION BUS']
}


master_df['Vehicle Type'] = master_df['Vehicle Class'].map(
    {v: k for k, vehicles in vehicle_type_dict.items() for v in vehicles}, na_action='ignore')
```

Read more about `.map()` --> [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)